# Deploy a Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment

I wonder if it is possible to deploy a web application that is not developped using google app engine. I mean if I have already a developed web application for example a Java EE project and I want just to deploy it using app engine. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Google recommends the use of eclipse to create projects. A J2EE eclipse enforces standard J2EE JSRs. So it will work fine in an ideal case scenario.

Comment: thank you for your response. do you please any link for a tutorial showing how to deploy a j2ee application in google app engine ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible just configure the Google App Engine Jetty server in eclipse just like you configure tomcat. Develop the project with a conventional J2EE web app structure. While running add the project in the GAE Jetty server and run it. It will automatically generate the app-engine.xml and other required files.

[Check this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform)